# How to Insert Data in Excel file from another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sheets

```
A
B
Master
```

I want to insert row in A Sheet and make it appear in Master Sheet

and same with B sheet

I am new to excel and using excel 2007.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what did you tried already?

Comment: welcome to SO. if you post your current attempt(s) and where's it failing and screenshot example of what you attempting to accomplish we can help much more swiftly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access cells in another sheet like this: =sheetName!A1; per example.

I don't think there's a way to automatically fill the "Master" sheet..